# I have python (path set) and Tensorflow installed and updated, yet Tensorflow doesn't import

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Although I have installed and updated python and tensorflow in vs code, I am still getting this error:

```
"message": "Import \"tensorflow\" could not be resolved",
```

this is happening from the line:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I have tried fixing the interpreter, I installed it from home brew and set it as my path:

```
% which python3 
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

```
py version: 3.11.7
tf version: 2.15.0
```

Comment: try importing TensorFlow classes, then if that does not work either we can address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using conda, Check the environment whether you set the environment to  your project or not. once the environment is set, check whether tensorflow is installed in that environment using